# convert an array from Php to kotlin

Tags: php, arrays, kotlin

I have this array in PHP and I want to convert it to kotlin. in kotlin there is set, list and map but none of them not work to my purpose. how can I do that?
(sometimes my value is Int and sometimes is an array that holds two Int)

```
$tes = array("position"=>[23,5], "id"=>"123");
var_dump($tes);

//array(2) {
//  ["position"]=>
//  array(2) {
//    [0]=>
//    int(23)
//   [1]=>
//    int(5)
//  }
//  ["id"]=>
//  string(3) "123"
//}
```

Comment: Encode to json and decode.

Comment: you don't want to do that in kotlin

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin we want to use typesafe data structures. Rather than using poorly typed associative arrays, you can abstract the data in a proper class:

```
data class WhatEver(val id: String, val position: Pair<Int, Int>)

WhatEver("123", Pair(23,5)) //WhatEver(id=123, position=(23, 5))
```